# Restrict none logged in users in GitLab to Explore contents

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

On my own hosted GitLab CE installation there is an Explore link so that that gives read access for no logged in users. How can I disable that?

Comment: Do you want to make your gitlab not accessible to outside users (people without an account) or do you want to prevent your users from creating public projects i.e. projects that end up being visible and accessible on the Explore page?

Comment: Mainly preventing them to create public projects.

Comment: Ok, then my answer below should cover that, see the restrict link in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable this link , but you can redirect it back to the sign-in page for anonymous users.

```
cd /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/controllers/
sudo cp application_controller.rb application_controller.rb.orig
sudo vim application_controller.rb
```

and add the following code snippets to application_controller.rb

```
...
 before_action :force_authenticated_user!
...
def force_authenticated_user!(*args)
    if (!current_user) and (["/explore", "/help", "/public", "/users/password/new", "/users/password/edit"].include?(request.path))
        redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
    end
end
...
```

or better method for all paths (with subdirectory):

```
...
 before_action :force_authenticated_user!
...
def force_authenticated_user!(*args)
     if (!current_user) and (["/users/sign_in", "/users/password","/uploads/-/system/appearance/header_logo/1/your_logo.PNG","/users/auth/ldapmain/callback"].exclude?(request.path))
            redirect_to new_user_session_path and return
    end
end
...
```

Comment: If I use either of those, my password reset no longer works, it gets redirected. http://githost/users/password/edit?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set up the visibility your project as private or internal. Besides that I think the repository should configured to be viewed only by my team members for extra layer of security.

These are my settings of some projects I have hosted there and they do not appear in the Explore section. You can check them in the `Settings` tab of each project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to still have the Explore section but want to prevent outside users from cloning projects, then you need to set those projects to `Internal` visibility level.

[Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/public_access/public_access.html#visibility-of-projects) is a sumary of the different visibility levels. As an admin, you can [restrict](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/public_access/public_access.html#restricting-the-use-of-public-or-internal-projects) projects from being set as `Public` and only allow `Private` and `Internal` levels.